# I'm having trouble building color swatches using the json export feature of Herman for sassDocs

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, herman

Questions: 
I have a `sass-to-json.css` where the only think printed is the comment that exports from `@include herman-export;`. Do I need to manually un-comment that JSON and/or rename the file to have a json extension?

My `.sassdocrc` file:

```
dest: public/docs
theme: node_modules/sassdoc-theme-herman
verbose: true

herman:
  sass:
    sass.jsonfile: public/json/sass-to-json.css
```

Then my sass-to-json.scss file just has the two imports where herman code exists, and the export mixin. (I'm not sure if all of this is necessary, but the json compiles correctly)

```
@import "utilities";
@import "base/colors";
@include herman-export;
```

compiles to sass-to-json.css. I have tried removing the comment so it's valid json and renaming the file to .json. But I get the same result, which is that herman compiles the page without the swatches, and without errors:

```
/*! json-encode: {"colors": {"theme": {"shade": "#16161e", "tint": "#f0f0fb", "dark-grey": "#393946", "grey": "#7d8c9c", "white": "#fff", "black": "#000", "blue": "#0c55b7", "green": "#3fbb26", "yellow": "#e7b60a", "red": "#e71b46"}}} */
```

The relevant bits of my colors.scss file:

```
/// @group color
/// @colors theme
$theme: (
  'shade': #16161e,
  'tint': #f0f0fb,
  'dark-grey': #393946
);

@include herman-add('colors', 'theme', $theme);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Sass (and usage of `herman-add` and `herman-export`) looks great! No need to mess with the contents of the generated `sass-to-json.scss` file; it's supposed to be a valid Sass comment, and Herman itself will take care of parsing it as valid JSON.

The docs are a bit unclear, but the relevant option here is `jsonfile` nested under the `sass` option, not `sass.jsonfile`. So for example:

```
dest: public/docs
theme: herman
verbose: true

herman:
  sass:
    jsonfile: public/json/sass-to-json.css
```

(Note that you can also just specify `herman` as the theme, and SassDoc will automatically look for `node_modules/sassdoc-theme-herman`.)